# How to find all the ips associated with one host?

Tags: php, linux, tcp, dns, ip

I want to find all the IP(s) of a specific host for example yahoo.com or facebook.com I know they have more than one IP. what is the best way?

Comment: look at dns tools, `dig` is a good one to start

Comment: It's not possible, since the host may have private interfaces you have no access to, with unpublished IP addresses.  Perhaps you don't actually mean *all* IPs?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for in PHP is [`dns_get_record`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php). It will get the actual DNS records, which *can* include multiple IP addresses (`A` records). Note that this may not always give you *all* IPs because of DNS-based load balancing solutions.

Example from PHP.net:

```
<?php
$result = dns_get_record("php.net");
print_r($result);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => php.net
            [type] => MX
            [pri] => 5
            [target] => pair2.php.net
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 6765
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [host] => php.net
            [type] => A
            [ip] => 64.246.30.37
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 8125
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is simply look up the A and AAAA records. I assume you want to do this with Linux since that's one of the tags. To do that, you can run a command like `dig yahoo.com`. For more details, check out `man dig`. If you don't have `dig` installed, it can be installed with a package manager.

For PHP, check out the `dns_get_record()` function.

Do note that sometimes, big companies use the same IP for multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to try *dig*, which is part of the [BIND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIND) suit. It's a great tool for exploring the Domain Name System.

IP addresses bound to a particular domain are listed under the ANSWER SECTION. Additionally, you get a list of related DNS servers and their addresses.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$ dig yahoo.com
...

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;yahoo.com.             IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
yahoo.com.      2131    IN  A   98.138.253.109
yahoo.com.      2131    IN  A   98.139.183.24
yahoo.com.      2131    IN  A   72.30.38.140

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
yahoo.com.      65928   IN  NS  ns4.yahoo.com.
...

ns4.yahoo.com.  65928   IN  A   68.142.196.63
...
```